# I get 500 (Internal Server Error) when WCF has object parameters with (Ajax)

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

I'm new with Web Service and Ajax. I'm trying to build WCF App (restful API). Currently I'm facing some problems when I send js object to WCF. Also when I add `[WebInvoke(UriTemplate= "foo")]` to any method in Service, I got error in all methods in the Service.

This is My ajax

```
  $("#Insert").click(function () {
            var employee = {};
            employee.Id = "0";
            employee.Name = $("#nametext").val();
            employee.Nationality = $("#nationalitytext").val();
            employee.Email = $("#emailtext").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '../GetEmployee.svc/insertEmpoyee',
                method: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                data: '{emp:' + JSON.stringify(employee) + '}',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function () {

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log('{emp:' + JSON.stringify(employee) + '}');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(employee));
                }
            });

        });
```

This is my WCF Service

```
 public void insertEmpoyee(Employee emp)
    {

        String strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBSC"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProInsertEmployeeData", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() {
                ParameterName = "@Name",
                Value = emp.Name
            });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@NameNationality",
                Value = emp.Nationality
            });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Email",
                Value = emp.Email
            });

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Open();
        }
    }
```

This is Service Contract

```
 [ServiceContract(Name = "../GetEmployee", Namespace = "http://localhost:51520")]
public interface IGetEmployee
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate= "insertEmpoyee")]
    Employee byId(int id);

    [OperationContract]
    List<Employee> getAll();

    [OperationContract]
    void insertEmpoyee(Employee emp);
}
```

This the Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Getempbe">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AjaxAndWCF.GetEmployeeAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="AjaxAndWCF.GetEmployee" behaviorConfiguration="Getempbe">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxAndWCF.GetEmployeeAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="AjaxAndWCF.IGetEmployee" >
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>

    </endpoint>

  </service>
</services>
```

Thanks for all of you.

Comment: As far as REST service is considered, ServiceContract attribute plays no role at all.

Comment: I solved it by replacing the object parameter with Multiple String parameters. but still I wish to know the way how to pass js object to WCF object that would be very interesting to me. Happy new year!!!